# SQLite data are not retrieved at second run of the game, but only at relaunch

Tags: python, sqlite

I implemented a SQLite db on Alien Invasion (*Python Crash Course*, 2nd Edition, by *Eric Matthes*) to store high scores. As you can see there is a Play button to start a run and, on top of the screen, the current score and the high-score.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRQMt.jpg

When first launching the game, the highest score stored in the db is correctly retrieved, and when a run is finished, in case you did the  highest score, it gets also correctly stored.

**Issue**: if I do the highest score and then I go play a second run, it still shows the previous high-score. My high-score is shown only at the re-launch of the app, despite being correctly stored.

I know there is a lot to be improved in here, so all constructive suggestions will be warmly welcomed.

Thanks for having a look at it:

(edited)

alien_invasion.py

```
class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage the app"""

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()
        ...

        self.stats = GameStats(self)
        self.play_button = Button(self, "Play")
        self.scoreboard = Scoreboard(self)
        
    def _create_fleet(self):
        ...

    def _create_alien(self, alien_number, row_number):
        ...

    def _check_keydown(self, event):
        ...

    def _check_keyup(self, event):
        ...

    def check_events(self):
        ...
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                self._check_play_button(mouse_pos)

    def _check_play_button(self, mouse_pos):
        button_clicked = self.play_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
        if button_clicked and not self.stats.game_active:
            self.settings.dynamic_settings()
            self.stats.reset_stats()
            self.stats.game_active = True
            self._provide_highscore()
            self.scoreboard._prep_score()
            self.scoreboard._prep_high_score()
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

            self.aliens.empty()
            self.bullets.empty()

            self._create_fleet()
            self.ship.center_ship()

            self.scoreboard.show()

    def _update_bullets(self):
        ...

    def _check_fleet_edges(self):
        ...

    def _update_aliens(self):
        ...

    def _change_fleet_direction(self):
        ...

    def _fire_bullet(self):
        ...

    def update_screen(self):
        ...

    def _ship_hit(self):
        # To keep playing in case you still have ships, or new run.
        # In case of high score, store it.
        if self.stats.ships_left > 1:
            self.stats.ships_left -= 1
            self.aliens.empty()
            self.bullets.empty()

            self._create_fleet()
            self.ship.center_ship()

            sleep(1.5)
        else:
            self.add_high_score()
            self.stats.game_active = False
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

    def _provide_highscore(self):
# Open DB and provide the (name, score) tuple for the high score
        db = sqlite3.connect("highscores.sqlite")
        cursor = db.cursor()

        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS highscores (name TEXT, score INTEGER)")

        for name, score in cursor.execute("SELECT name, MAX(score)  FROM highscores").fetchall():
            return name, score

        cursor.close()
        db.commit()
        db.close()

    def add_high_score(self):
    # Storing high score
        if self.stats.score > self.stats.high_score[1]:
            db = sqlite3.connect("highscores.sqlite")
            # self.name = input("Please enter your name: ")
            self.new_high = self.stats.score
            self.scoreboard._prep_high_score()
            # name_input = InputBox # todo need to fix this name value
            self.name = self.input_name()
            add_sql = 'INSERT INTO highscores VALUES (?, ?)'
            db.execute(add_sql, (self.name, self.new_high))
            db.commit()

            db.close()
            # return self.new_high

    def input_name(self):
        .....

    def _check_alien_bottom(self):
        .....
                

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the MAIN LOOP"""
        while True:
            self.check_events()
            if self.stats.game_active:
                self.ship.update()
                self._update_bullets()
                self._update_aliens()
            self.update_screen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

game_stats.py

```
class GameStats:
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
          ...
          self.high_score = ai_game._provide_highscore()
```

scoreboard.py

```
import pygame.font

class Scoreboard:
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        ....
        self._prep_high_score()

    def _prep_score(self):
        .....

    def show(self):
        ....

    def _prep_high_score(self):
        high_score = round(self.stats.high_score[1], -1)
        # high_score = round(self.stats.scoreboard.highest_score)
        high_score_str = str("{:,}".format(high_score))
        high_scorer = self.stats.high_score[0]

        self.high_score_img = self.font.render(high_score_str, True, self.text_color, self.settings.bg_color)
        self.high_scorer_img = self.font.render(high_scorer, True, self.text_color, self.settings.bg_color)

        self.high_score_rect = self.high_score_img.get_rect()
        self.high_scorer_rect = self.high_scorer_img.get_rect()

        self.high_score_rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.high_score_rect.top = self.score_rect.top

        self.high_scorer_rect.right = self.high_score_rect.left - 15
        self.high_scorer_rect.top = self.high_score_rect.top
```

Full project:
https://github.com/rpiflv/Alien-Invasion

Comment: sorry for posting the full project. Question has been edited

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to fix it by updating `self.stats.high_score` in the `def _ship_hit(self)` as follows:

alien_invasion.py:

```
def _ship_hit(self):
    # To keep playing in case you still have ships, or new run.
    # In case of high score, store it, *and update the high score*
    if self.stats.ships_left > 1:
        ...
    else:
        if self.stats.score > self.stats.high_score[1]:
            self.add_high_score()
            self.stats.high_score = self.name, self.new_high
        self.stats.game_active = False
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your `_provide_highscore()` method:

```py
    def _provide_highscore(self):

        db = sqlite3.connect("highscores.sqlite")
        cursor = db.cursor()

        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS highscores (name TEXT, score INTEGER)")
        # db.execute('INSERT INTO highscores VALUES ("FLA", 1000000)')
        # db.execute('INSERT INTO highscores VALUES ("ANG", 1500000)')
        # db.execute('INSERT INTO highscores VALUES ("KAL", 500000)')

        for name, score in cursor.execute("SELECT name, MAX(score)  FROM highscores").fetchall():
            return name, score

        cursor.close()
        db.commit()
        db.close()
```

A function stops executing as soon as it hits a return statement. It looks like you have a loop here that will only ever execute once, and on the first iteration of the loop it will return a tuple containing a name and a score. The last three lines never run. I haven't used SQLite much at all so I'm not sure if this is the issue, but this is one place I'd start investigating.

Also, when there's a new high score you're clearly writing it to the db. But are you ever updating `self.stats.high_score`?

Comment: thanks japhyr for the hint, I fixed it. I will post an answer to show the solution. 

ps: your book is great!