# Prevent file resetting to original state using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am creating the exe of game made with pygame using pyinstaller. I am storing the highscore in a text file. The command is -

`pyinstaller main.py --windowed --onefile --add-data "assets;assets"`

The assets folder has the text file. Now the highscore functionality works fine for one session. But when I close the exe and open it again, the file resets to its original state.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Have you tried compiling without the `add-data` tag and just kept the application in the original directory?

Comment: PyInstaller will extract all your resources into a temporary location and then clean them up once the program exits. This is why the high score file resets. You should create a persistent file in `%APPDATA%\<your program name>`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10563148/2280890) for more details.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Will try and then revert.

Comment: @SlavaCat That would not keep it onefile

Comment: It would keep the executable in one file, but data would be stored elsewhere. I much prefer this method, but if it doesn't work for you, you might want to try import random's solution.

Comment: Ok! @importrandom if I do that I would need to provide the users an installer to create the folder. They will not be able to directly use the exe.

Comment: @SlavaCat If I do doing this the user will be able to change the highscore.

Comment: Your application will need to handle creation of the highscores file if it doesn't exist. If you're on Windows, you could store information in the Registry using the in-built [winreg](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html) module.

Comment: Encryption? I really don't know a whole lot about pyinstaller and the method I suggested is just what I do when I encounter issues like this. Sorry if I'm not much of a help.

Comment: @importrandom So should I prefer using the registry or the AppData folder?

Comment: Thank you! I resorted to using the appdata directory using appdirs module.

Comment: A file is probably easier to get working. If you're using a dictionary to store scores, you can use built-in `json.loads` and `json.dumps` to process the string data you read/write to your file. 
You can also answer your own question so that future seekers who stumble upon this question have an answer.

Comment: @importrandom Ok! Is it viable to use a `.db` file with python's sqlite3 module, or should I just use a file?

Comment: A file may be simpler, but a database can be a more elegant solution. Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67356620/2280890) will get you started.

Comment: @importrandom Ok! Thank you for you help!